# Install SSL certificate for Jenkins

Tags: ssl, jenkins, ssl-certificate, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

My SSL certificate for Jenkins server is about to expire and I would like to renew it. To do so,

- I got my new SSL certificate
- Added the new SSL certificate as a pem file to the Jenkins certificate trust store using keytool
- Restarted Jenkins service

But when I checked the certificate using chrome I'm still seeing the validity of old certificate. Is there something I'm missing?

I also have a .key file along with the certificate, should I add that to. If so how do I add it?

Comment: You might have to remove old certificate first using keytool.